# regular languages under intersection and union, a bit of confusion to clarify

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Let's assume that $L_1 = a^nb^{2n}$ and $L_2 = a^na^{2n}$, knowing that $L_1$ is not regular, and $L_2$ is. We also know that regular languages are closed under intersection and union, and complement. What can we say about $L_3 = L_1^\complement$ and $L_4 = L_2^ \complement$?

It seems correct to say $L_4$ is regular, because $L_2$ is, but since $L_1$ is not regular, can we say about $L_3$ the same?

Also, let's assume we have two irregular languages $L_5$ and $L_6$, can we say about their intersection and union as being irregular as well?

Comment: Are you allowed to refer to the closure property that regular languages are closed under complement?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

Since $L_3$ is the complement of $L_1$, $L_1$ is likewise the complement of $L_3$. If $L_3$ was regular, what would that imply regarding the regularity of $L_1$?

For $L_5$ and $L_6$, consider for example the case where the two languages are each others' complements. Can you determine what languages result from the union and intersection of a language and its complement? Are these languages regular?

Comment: For the last question, the resulting is $L \cap L^\complement = \epsilon$ which is regular. But you re missing something, we only know this: if $L$ is regular, and $L_1$ is regular, then their intersection or union is regular, we can have regular intersection irregular give regular or non regular, and we can have the intersection of two non regular languages give a regular or a non regular. My question is simple, and you repeated my questions

Comment: I am trying to get my facts checked with from someone an expert, that s why I came here